# How to customize the acronym / abbreviations list?

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

I have finished writing my report that contains about 100 pages with a lot of acronyms but i didn't manage them while writing the report.

Now i want to customize the acronym list to be generated because the convention i have done is as follows `LNR (latex nomenclature report)`

Is there any method to generate the acronym list from that format wich i have used for all acronyms

I don't want to manually do something like this for every acronym:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$Nmmm$}{le nombre d'éléments}
Supposons que $Nmmm$...
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

thanks

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (we don't know how you create your list at the first place – I can think of at least four different packages for the task)

Comment: @clemens i haven't created any list yet but i've found the method described above (updated) but i don't want to use for every acronym .. it will be too much time consuming , thanks

Comment: You can extract the acronyms and their definitions to a separate file using regular expressions (maybe a bit tricky, but not that hard). At that point, it will be more or less trivial to "wrap" them with the appropriate LaTeX commands of your package of choice (e.g. glossaries) and then include that file in your preamble.

Comment: @ZéLoff thanks but how can i do this , have you any examples ?

Comment: If you're on a UNIX machine (Linux, OS X, BSD...) you can try something like this:
`grep -Eo '[A-Z]{1,} \([A-Za-z0-9 ]*\)' test.tex > acrlist.txt`
Note that this has some limitations, the main one being the acronym and its definition have to be on a single line.
If you're using Windows you'll probably need something like MinGW to get `grep`.
Also, this isn't meant to be an answer (I don't have time for it, at the moment), just a starting point...

Comment: @ZéLoff i'm actually on windows but i have cygwin installed ... ihave tested it and was able to output the acronyms i have used ... can you tell me the next step ? thanks

Comment: If you got one acronym per line you can now "wrap" the definitions in `\nomenclature{}{}` with something like
`sed -e 's/\([A-Z]*\) (\(.*\))/\\nomenclature{$\1$}{\2}/' acrlist.tex > acrlist2.tex`
And then copy-paste this into your file, or use `\input{acrlist2.tex}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
grep -Eo '[A-Z]{1,} \([A-Za-z0-9 ]*\)' test.tex > acrlist.txt
```

Note that this has some limitations, the main one being the acronym and its definition have to be on a single line. Better results can be obtained if using something PCRE-capable.

Now that you have one acronym per line you can "wrap" them in your LaTeX commands of choice, like `\nomenclature`, from the `nomencl` package or `\newacronym` from `glossaries`:

```
sed -e 's/\([A-Z]*\) (\(.*\))/\\nomenclature{$\1$}{\2}/' acrlist.txt > acrlist2.tex
```

You can then insert the acronym file in your main `.tex` file using `\input`. And you can also pipe `grep` and `sed` together to avoid creating the intermediate file.

*Caveats: As noted, the regexes above might not work perfectly with all cases, do check the final result manually. And if you're using Windows you'll probably need something like MinGW to get `grep` and `sed`.*

Comment: i do have minGw installed too but after inserting the second line containing sed command it gives me undefined control sequence ... have you tested the solution

Comment: Yes, I did (on OS X, but shouldn't make a difference). I assume it is LaTeX giving you the "undefined command sequence" error. Did you check the file created by `sed` (`acrlist2.tex` in my example) for errors?

Comment: the file was not created but i can use the first produced file to do the operation manually